# Cannot connect in sharepoint with NTLM authentication

Tags: java, sharepoint, ntlm

I'm trying to stablish a connection with sharepoint but never touch this before. I found this code to authenticate but it doesn't work.

I'm in a company with a proxy.

I believe I'm a normal user in SharePoint (not sure).

SharePoint is like this: https://company.sharepoint.com (Replacing real name for company)

What am I doing wrong?

**CODE:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        System.out.println(credsProvider.toString());
        credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
                new NTCredentials("me@company.com",
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Password", ""), "https:\\company.sharepoint.com",workstation));/*--------this-------*/
        System.out.println(credsProvider.toString());
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
        System.out.println(httpclient.toString());
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https:\\company.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx");
            System.out.println(httpget.toString());
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Also what should I put in workstation?

**ERROR:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to company.sharepoint.com:443 [company.sharepoint.com/150.151.150.152] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: The error message has imo nothing to do with sharepoint nor with ntlm. Since you stated, you're behind a proxy, I'm pretty sure, that's the problem. And since you're using httpclient, you might find this link useful: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java

Comment: @slowy - Thank you the proxy works now. What should I do with the credential provider in order to acces sharepoint. It says "This could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed request.".